# Convert expression in string to a value

Tags: php

I have a string with following statement:

```
$expr = "20 * 10 + 5";
echo $expr;
```

If I print the above string, then it shows me following output:

```
20 * 10 + 5
```

If I do as `echo (float)$expr`
then it shows wrong output as `20`

I want full calculated value as `205`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285140/calculate-numbers-from-string

Comment: @user_1330: I check and let you know.